# Understanding the type of the cast operator in Scrap Your Boilerplate

Tags: haskell, scrap-your-boilerplate

In the 2003 [Scrap Your Boilerplate paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/) by Laemmel and SPJ there is a code snippet on page 3

```
mkT :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (b -> b) -> a -> a
mkT f = case cast f of
   Just g -> g
   Nothing -> id
```

and then the paper explains

> That is, mkT f x applies f to x if x's type is the same as f's argument type

Following in the pattern of the preceding examples in the paper, I would think the type of `cast f` would have to be compared with the type `Maybe (b -> b)` for the above to evaluate to `Just g`, but this seems incorrect.

What is going on here with the signature of `cast f`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `cast`is

```
cast :: (Typeable x, Typeable y) => x -> Maybe y
```

it produces `Nothing` if `x` and `y` are different types and `Just argument` if they are the same. Note that the result type, `y` must be determined from the calling context when `cast` is used. If it isn't, compilation fails with an unresolved overloading/ambiguous type variable error.

In this particular example, the types are function types, `(b -> b)` for the argument, and `(a -> a)` for the result. So

```
cast f :: Maybe (a -> a)
```

and `mkT` could also be written `mkT = fromMaybe id . cast`.

Comment: `cast` inspects the `TypeRep` of `f` and compares it with the `TypeRep` of the demanded type. If the `TypeRep`s are the same, it returns `Just f`, otherwise `Nothing`.

Comment: I think I see now. I was missing the basic notion of how right-hand typeclass constraints work. I want to accept your answer, but could you edit/clarify w.r.t. how `cast` in this example 'fills in' its right typeclass constraint with the right-hand portion `(a -> a)` of the signature of `mkT` (since `->` is right-associative)?

Comment: The right-hand-side type must be determined by the calling context, like it must be for `read` (or `fromIntegral`, but there's type defaulting for that one). Does that clarify it?

Comment: Yes, I had an "aha" moment when I looked a bit closer at the context of `cast` and realized I had no idea what was going on with `Typeable y`, and then I found an answer with the `read` example at http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses